# Xtext Xtype: What's the difference between JvmType and JvmTypeReference?

Tags: java, xtext

The Xtype grammar contains two ways to refer to Java types: `JvmType` and `JvmTypeReference`.

I don't understand:

- why there are two;
- how they are different;
- when I should use which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JvmType` is an EMF view on (the declaration of) a Java type. It's subtypes represent the different kinds of types in Java, such as classes and interfaces (`JvmGenericType`), enums (`JvmEnum`) and annotation types (`JvmAnnotationType`) or primitive types (`JvmPrimitiveType`).

`JvmTypeReference` is a reference to a declared type. It's cross-reference type points to an `JvmType`, but it can have additional properties such as type arguments ( `JvmParameterizedTypeReferece`). Java 8 would call the `JvmTypeReference` a "type use". most of its subclasses have a more technical nature, e.g. to represent stages of a partly resolved type during type inferrence.

As arrays are in a way hard-wired into Java's typesystem, `JvmArrayType` inherits from `JvmType` rather than being a specific `JvmTypeReference`.

Answer (score 2):

This remotely rings a bell from the time I was doing work with Eclipse's Java AST. There are two options on how *deeply* you want a Java file processed:

- just parsing;
- type binding.

When you use type binding, you get access to the actual Java *types* being referred to; without that you just get a *type reference*, which amounts to a parsed Java name.

Comment: I'm currently busy with Xtend, and while I'm no expert, this sounds about right.

Comment: Then the implementation is odd: `JvmTypeReference` has a getter for `JvmType`. So I wonder how it can create a `JvmType` when it's just parsing :-/

Comment: It will return null if it's not available. It's a confusing API.

Comment: In my case, the Java type is on the classpath but I get `JvmVoidImpl` :-(